# Stove, Cooker, Range, Oven, Hob

Tags: north-american-english

Whenever we go to Canada, we go self catering. Usually the cooker (English word for the combination of an oven with gas or electric burners on top which can be used when cooking with saucepans) we had the use of, was larger than the standard British cooker with much greater room inside and on top. I loved using them and I can’t seem to find anything like it over here in New Zealand.
I wondered if it is called something entirely different and I am just not using the correct name.

Comment: Get a picture of it and search images on Google. Good Luck.

Comment: Everything is bigger in North America. Well, not really, but cars, restaurant portions, and home appliances to be sure. Every country has slightly different, if overlapping, standard sizes for things like washing machines and refrigerators and whatnot; the large ranges are probably hard to find because they wouldn't fit in most Kiwi kitchens, not because they're called something different.

Comment: In everyday speech, we (AmE) call that a stove, but the appliance salesmen call it a range.

Comment: Shouldn't your tag be _New Zealand English_?

Answer (score 1):

This is a Fisher and Paykel brand "90cm Freestanding Dual Fuel Oven with Gas Cooktop" sold by Harvey Norman New Zealand. Please note: despite my name I have nothing to do with Harvey Norman - I never heard of them before I Googled "New Zealand cooker" (without the quotes). They also sell a Belling "dual range cooker" which is also 90 cm wide, and looks pretty similar.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For reference. In BE:
[image: For BE reference]
1 **Stove** - usually used for heating a room. Occasionally with an upper surface for heating a single kettle, etc. (also occasionally/regionally used for 2. Cooker.)

2 **Cooker** - has a hob (see 5), a grill and an oven.

3 **Range** - has multiple hobs and at least 2 ovens also has at least one grill and a perhaps a griddle and or a rotissery

4 **Oven** - solely for baking and roasting

5 **Hob** - a set, usually 4, of heating rings. More than 4 and it may be described as a "range".

The above are usually defined by the fuel they use. Gas/electricity combinations tend to be called "dual-fuel"

Comment: And in US - fireplace, range, big-ass range, oven, stovetop. Standard widths are 20", 24", 27" and 30"